# File or Directory not found when using script with git hooks

Tags: linux, git, shell, githooks

I'm currently trying to create a custom mLinux Image and I'm following the instructions from this website: http://www.multitech.net/developer/software/mlinux/mlinux-building-images/building-a-custom-linux-image/

I followed them and everything worked until this point.

When i'm trying to run the setup file (including this code:

```
set -e
BUILDCONF=build/conf/local.conf

if [ "$1" != "--update" ]; then
  echo ""
  echo "Setting up git hooks..."
ln -s ../../scripts/git-hooks/post-merge .git/hooks/post-merge || true
ln -s ../../scripts/git-hooks/post-checkout .git/hooks/post-checkout || 
true
  ln -s ../../scripts/git-hooks/pre-commit .git/hooks/pre-commit || true
  ln -s ../../scripts/git-hooks/pre-push .git/hooks/pre-push || true
fi

echo ""
echo "Updating git submodules..."
git submodule update --init
```

)

I get the following Error Message for each of the Hooks:
Shortcut .gt/hooks/(name of the hook) could not be created: file or directory not found (translated from German).
Additionally also: git: submodule is not a command.
Has anybody got an idea, what I could have forgotten/ what is wrong?

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Is the script in the root directory of the git repository?

Comment: Hi, i don't know if I understood your question right. I run the Script locally on my Pc but cd into the cloned git repository beforehand.

Comment: I just checked with git rev-parse --show-toplevel and the root repository is the place the setup.sh file is in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [show here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55474732/6309)

> The yocto version I am using for Edison is this one: https://github.com/edison-fw/meta-intel-edison
>
> The problem happens because the git version on Edison board is missing some parts. In this case the git-submodules binary is missing in `/usr/libexec/git-core`

So check first if your Git installation is complete in your build environment.
If not, you might need to complete it with binaries taken from a more complete distribution.

Comment: Hi, you were right, i missed a git clone command and therefore didn't have all the necessary Repositorys. Thank you!